# typescript object is possibly null even though it's in if statement checking

Tags: typescript

This is my code:

```
if (user !== null) {
        const userAddys = user.wallets.filter((wallet: { provider: string; }) => wallet.provider === 'metamask');
        addMetamaskAddress(userAddys);
    }
```

This is still giving me an error that user is possibly null.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/N53q9W) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: What is the exact error? Because your code works fine if I add a definition and type for `user`. The answer to this question depends on how `user` is typed, which you have not included in your code.